# jQuery | Preencher input e pesquisar ajax (Pesquisa ajax já funcionando)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Boas, estou com um problema.
Já possuo no site um campo Search em Ajax que funciona perfeitamente, quando vou digitando ele já faz a busca. OK.

Porem estou implementando isso em um site WP, e coloquei via jQuery o codigo abaixo para atribuir um value para o campo e simular a tecla enter para pesquisa. Porem não resulta.
Se eu der um espaço que seja e enter, funcina.
Segue meu codigo, poderiam me dar uma pista.

PS: Não possuo botao

```
/* PREENCHE AUTOMATICAMENTE O NOME DO CURSO / CALENDARIO */ 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        
    jQuery("#mec_sf_s_9741").attr('value', 'Teste 1');
    
    var e = $.Event( "keyup", { keyCode: 13 } );
    jQuery('#mec_sf_s_9741').trigger(e);
    
    
});
```

Onde esta escrito Teste 1 já é preenchido automaticamente.

Gratidão.

Comment: Será que não tem algum script do WP desfazendo o bind da tecla? Você já tentou refazer bind pelo console, depois que a página já carretou totalmente?

Comment: Já tentei no evento bind também e nada.

Comment: mas você fez o que eu disse? deixar a página carregar, depois de baixar todos os resources e depois no console executar o bloco que está dentro do ready.

Comment: Sim, via console depois de tudo carregado. Ele altera o value e não faz mais nada. Tbm não apresenta erro. Não consigo saber se o evento esta acontecendo.

Comment: Ok, mas o seu objetivo é submeter o form no keyup do enter? Qual é o id do form?

Comment: Eu possuo um campos input de pesquisa que atribuo o value  "XXX" via jquery após o carregamento da pagina. Quero simular que o usuario preencheu e deu enter! O código abaixo funciona, mas nao executa a pesquia.                              jQuery( "input[id^='mec_sf_s_9901']" ).val( "SD" ); var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { keyCode: 13 } );

jQuery(document).on('keypress', function(event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 13) {
       jQuery( "mec_sf_s_9901" ).focus();
       alert("ENTER  pressed...");
    }
});

//
//  press ENTER
//
jQuery(document).trigger(e);

Comment: Não é mais fácil você submter o formulário ou executar o método que faz a busca? Você não deve "simular" inputs do usuário e isso é desnecessário, se o você tem o controle do DOM...

Comment: O problema é que estou a utilizar o WP com o Plugin que faz a pesquisa. Ex: tenho 2 cursos no google calendário, os eventos começam com AA ou BB, então na pagina se o usuário entrar no curso AA eu quero exibir as próximas datas só para AA. Por isso preciso de forma autónoma de preencher o campo de pesquisa com AA e simular o enter para ele filtrar.

Comment: leia a documentação do plugin, com certeza ele deve apresentar uma forma melhor de fazer isso

Comment: Não tem esse recurso, já informaram (ele só importa um calendário) eu criei essa forma adicionando as duas letras no inicio do Evento para assim poder filtrar entre AA e BB. baseado na pagina eu busco AA ou BB. Percebeu? Eu vi que o campo de filtro dispara um envento chamado search(), mas ele nao reconhece esse evento direto no meu codigo. Deve ser uma funcao do proprio plugin. teria como fazer um "include" das duas classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei por eu mesmo resolver, compartilho solução.

Como o campo busca também realiza a busca via ajax, alterei trigger para CHANGE  e trabalhou certinho.

```
    jQuery('input#mec_sf_s_9741').val('texto para pesquisa');
    jQuery('input#mec_sf_s_9741').trigger('change');
```